# How to deploy .net 3.5 application that is now using the task parallel library backport

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, task-parallel-library, backport

I am trying to put out a new version of an existing .net 3.5 application that now uses the task parallel library backport for .net 3.5. I know I need to distribute System.Threading.dll to the users (version 1.0.2856.102), but I am not sure where to put it. I thought just putting it in the same directory as the executable would do it, but I am still getting an exception. Is there something special I need to do on the user's machine to get it to recognize this dll?

Here is the exception:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException Message:Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was user error. The user led me to believe they put the dll in the application directory, but they didn't. Putting it in the application directory fixes the issue.